# How to add maven dependencies as classpath libraries to Eclipse plugin Runtime?

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, dependencies, classpath, tycho

I'm developing an eclipse plugin and I'm in the process of converting it to Maven project. I used "Configure->Convert to Maven project" option and wrote the pom.xml file with the appropriate dependencies and a reference to tycho and to maven plugin.

```
<properties>
    <tycho.version>0.23.0</tycho.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeAllDependencies>true</includeAllDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <artifact>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </artifact>
                </target>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <ws>gtk</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                    <environment>
                        <os>macosx</os>
                        <ws>cocoa</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, maven dependency libraries are not automatically added to the project's classpath and even when I tried adding them to .classpath file e.g.
`<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/net/sf/jung/jung-api/2.0.1/jung-api-2.0.1.jar"/>` (M2_REPO classpath variable is configured) I was still getting an exception for missing classes in the MANIFEST file.

Is it possible in eclipse to set the classpath outside the project's root and if yes is it possible to automatically add the maven dependency libraries to the classpath of the project?

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse plugin only takes osgi bundles and plugins as its dependency. If you are giving the dependency as normal jar it wont take. Manifest file will take the plugins and bundles which are available in the p2 repository of eclipse home ,target definition file or from the eclipse site. So i suggest you to convert the maven dependency jar to osgi bundle or plugin and add it as a dependency to eclipse plugin so you wont get any error during maven build.